# android forward json data to another class with listview

Tags: android, json, listview

I`m using JSON to parse data from mysql table, with "id" and "firstname" rows, and populate listview with "firstname" row and its working fine. But, I want to add onListItemClick and when user clicks on some name on listview, the "id" value for that name should be forwarded to another class. This is how I populate listview:

```
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                r.add(json_data.getString("firstname"));

            }

            dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Persons.this,
                    R.layout.person_row, r);
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

and I can forward "firstname" to other class with this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String FirstName = o.toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, PersonDetails.class);
    Bundle bandl = new Bundle();
    bandl.putString("fn", FirstName);
    i.putExtras(bandl);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

But the problem is that I want to display "firstname" on listview and onClick to forward only "id" to other class, and I cant figure that out. Forwarding "firstname" to other class and then retreiving other mysql data worked fine until I got two people with same name, so that`s why I need to forward row "id" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a custom class CustomPerson with 2 attributes : id and firstName. In CustomPerson override toString to return firstName.

ArrayAdapter Creation :

```
// list should be a List<CustomPerson> and should be filled with your data
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomPerson>(Persons.this, R.layout.person_row, list);
```

OnListItemClick implementation |:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    CustomPerson o = (CustomPerson) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    long id = o.getId();
    // DO SOMETHING WITH the person's id

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints guys, but I`m afraid I will stick to forwarding names with sufix at the end, since this is little complicated for me :)

Answer (score 1):

simple short working answer to you

keep a referecne to the `JsonArray`  where you can access it in the `onListItemClick`

so you can do the following

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String id = jArray. getJSONObject(position).getString("id");
    Intent i = new Intent(this, PersonDetails.class);
    Bundle bandl = new Bundle();
    bandl.putString("id",id);
    i.putExtras(bandl);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

note you should make it better by change you Adapter to something that can hold both the id and the name. so you don't need to keep a reference to the JsonArray object. here is a [tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) for you .

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to get it working using this code:

```
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    try {

                        String ajdi = jArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("id").toString();
                        Intent i = new Intent(Persons.this, PersonDetails.class);
                        Bundle bandl = new Bundle();
                        bandl.putString("id", ajdi);
                        i.putExtras(bandl);
                        startActivity(i);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        ;
                    }
                }

            });
```

Thanks again both of you guys!